# Error: Illegal conversion from Boolean to List<Boolean>

Tags: apex

I am trying to invoke an Apex class from a Flow. Flow input will be Record ID and in the class, it checks certain conditions and once it is met- it will send out True or False output to the Flow.

However, I keep on receiving this error: Illegal conversion from Boolean to List.

My code is as follows:

```
public class CheckChallengeEligibity {
    @InvocableMethod (label = 'Check for challenge eligibity')
    public static List<Boolean> checkChallengeEligibility(List<IdeaChallengeWrapper> ideaChallengeLst){
        Idea_Challenge__c  challenge= [SELECT id, Title__c, Display_Filters__c, Challenge_Type__c, Challenge_Sub_Type__c, Inactive__c 
            FROM  Idea_Challenge__c  
            WHERE Inactive__c = FALSE AND Audience__c != null];

        User userRecord = [SELECT Id, Office_Location__c, Title, Name, FirstName, LastName, COSA__c,
                         L11__c, L8__c, Unit__c
                            From User
                            WHERE username = :UserInfo.getUsername()];

        Boolean isValid = challenge != null && IdeaConstants.CHALLENGE_TYPE_MEMBER_CHALLENGE != challenge.Challenge_Sub_Type__c;

        system.debug('test isvalid'+isvalid);

        if(isValid && userRecord != null && challenge.Display_Filters__c != null && challenge.Display_Filters__c.trim() != '')
        {
            isValid = false; //Filter is there, check for validity

            system.debug('challenge.Display_Filters__c.split()  '+challenge.Display_Filters__c.split('\\|'));

            for(String token : challenge.Display_Filters__c.split('\\|'))
            {
                if(token == null || token.trim() == '')
                {
                    continue;
                }

                token =  token.trim();
                system.debug('test '+token);

                // for(string  str:token){
                //  }

                if(token == userRecord.Office_Location__c || token == userRecord.COSA__c || token == userRecord.L11__c || token == userRecord.L8__c || token == userRecord.Unit__c || token == userRecord.Title)
                {
                    isValid = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

             return isValid;
        }

        for(IdeaChallengeWrapper challengeEligibility : ideaChallengeLst){
            isValid.add(false);
        }

        return isValid;
    }

    public class IdeaChallengeWrapper{
        @InvocableVariable public Boolean isValid;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method's data signature is returning a `List<Boolean>`, but you're trying to return a `Boolean`. You need to refactor the code so that each input has a corresponding output.